# Adding two arrays to create one

Tags: arrays, loops, addition

I've only been studying Java for a semester, and albeit I knew how learning goes when it comes to just the basics, it was fun and fairly easy as expected. However, toward the end things started to get a little rough for me with the introduction of Arrays and its involvement with loops. I'm currently trying to add two arrays together in order to make one. By making one, I mean:

Say for instance I've initialized two arrays like this: int[] T = {4, 5, 6} and int[] Y = {2, 3, 4}

How do I add them in order to make: {6, 8, 10} ?

I've played around and attempted to do this, but I know I'm very far off:

```
 public class Array_Add {

public static void main (String[] Args){

    int[] Eli = {4, 5 , 3};
    int[] Beck = {2, 5, 2};

    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < Eli.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < Beck.length; j++)
        sum = Eli[i] + Beck[j];
    }

    System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kannan Durai wrote, if you are sure the arrays always have same length, than this code should give you the desired result. Plus if you want an array of the results you should `.add()` them in a new `ArrayList<>()` in the `for()` loop, otherwise as it is in your code, you'll get just the last value of `sum` (in your case 3+2) because your `println` is outside the `for()` loop and is for the `int sum` which you didn't store anywhere. Try this code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[] Eli = {4, 5, 3};
            int[] Beck = {2, 5, 2};
            int sum = 0;
            ArrayList<Integer> total = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int i = 0; i < Eli.length; i++) {
                sum = Eli[i] + Beck[i];
                total.add(sum);
            }
            System.out.println(total);
        }
```

If you want to get every sum printed on the console individually than you don't need the `ArrayList<>()`. In that case try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
                int[] Eli = {4, 5, 3};
                int[] Beck = {2, 5, 2};
                int sum = 0;

                for(int i = 0; i < Eli.length; i++) {
                    sum = Eli[i] + Beck[i];
                    System.out.println(sum);
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to look this way to add two arrays:

```
 package arrayadd;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Arrayadd {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] firstArray = { 3,4,5 };
        int[] secondArray = { 5,6,7 };
        List<Integer> total = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        if(firstArray.length == secondArray.length) {
            for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
                int sum = firstArray[i] + secondArray[i];
                total.add(sum);
            }
            for ( Integer value : total) {
                System.out.println(value + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried modifying it and this is what I'm getting in the console: [I@15db9742[I@15db9742[I@15db9742

Comment: i have shared latest code and please try to run it and you will get the result what you need.

Comment: hi Zepheriah, is it fine and have you checked?

Comment: Yes, I have fixed it now. Thank you